# heroku deploy error, i can't understand Error Message

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have a problem with my deploy.
I build app with React.js and Node.js.
git push heroku master is success but the distributed page gave me an error message.
"Application error"

So I typed "heroku logs --tail" and the result is below.

---

```
2022-03-15T14:56:49.292265+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-03-15T14:57:07.431515+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-03-15T14:57:08.742340+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-03-15T14:57:08.742355+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-novel2.6@1.0.0 start
2022-03-15T14:57:08.742355+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2022-03-15T14:57:08.742356+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-03-15T14:57:08.941718+00:00 app[web.1]: localhost
2022-03-15T14:57:08.948568+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:91
2022-03-15T14:57:08.948570+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err0;
2022-03-15T14:57:08.948570+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-03-15T14:57:08.948570+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-03-15T14:57:08.948571+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/client'
2022-03-15T14:57:08.948571+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1336:3)
2022-03-15T14:57:08.948572+00:00 app[web.1]: at sync (/app/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:72:13)
2022-03-15T14:57:08.948572+00:00 app[web.1]: at sync (/app/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:78:24)
2022-03-15T14:57:08.948572+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.sync (/app/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:78:24)
2022-03-15T14:57:08.948573+00:00 app[web.1]: at new DiskStorage (/app/node_modules/multer/storage/disk.js:21:12)
2022-03-15T14:57:08.948573+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.module.exports [as diskStorage] (/app/node_modules/multer/storage/disk.js:65:10)
2022-03-15T14:57:08.948574+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:31:24)
2022-03-15T14:57:08.948574+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
2022-03-15T14:57:08.948575+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
2022-03-15T14:57:08.948575+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
2022-03-15T14:57:08.948576+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -30,
2022-03-15T14:57:08.948576+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'mkdir',
2022-03-15T14:57:08.948576+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'EROFS',
2022-03-15T14:57:08.948576+00:00 app[web.1]: path: '/client'
2022-03-15T14:57:08.948577+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-03-15T14:57:09.120748+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-03-15T14:57:09.218068+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-03-15T14:57:09.249117+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-03-15T14:57:24.426345+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
```

Maybe this is the problem?

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/client/build/index.html"));
});
```

and,
As you said, I will upload the react component to which I want to upload the image file.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useContext } from "react";
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
import "../../css/CreateNovel/Createnovel.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faXmark } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { ThemeContext } from "../../ThemeContext/ThemeContext";
import { SimpleFileUpload } from "react-simple-file-upload";

const Createnovel = ({ userObj }) => {
  const { setIsPost } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const { setIsSpinnerLoading } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const { setCreateComplete } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const { setIsExistSameNovel } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  const inputRef = useRef();
  const fileInput = useRef();
  const [createnovel, setCreatenovel] = useState({
    title: "",
    plot: "",
  });

  const [messagecondition, setMessagecondition] = useState(false);
  const [attachment, setAttachment] = useState();
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const [uploadedImg, setUploadedImg] = useState({
    fileName: "",
    fillPath: "",
  });

  const getValue = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setCreatenovel({
      ...createnovel,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const messageHandler = (res) => {
    if (res.data === false) {
      setCreateComplete(true);
    } else if (res.data === true) {
      setIsExistSameNovel(true);
    }
    setIsSpinnerLoading(false);
    console.log(!res.data);
  };

  const onCreatenovelBtnClick = () => {
    setIsPost(true);
    const id = userObj.uid;
    const formData = new FormData();
    if (content) {
      formData.append("img", content);
      axios.post("/upload", formData).then((res) => {
        axios
          .post("/create", {
            title: createnovel.title,
            plot: createnovel.plot,
            id: id,
            displayName: userObj.displayName,
            image: res.data.fileName,
          })
          .then((res) => {
            messageHandler(res);
          });
      });
    } else {
      axios
        .post("/create", {
          title: createnovel.title,
          plot: createnovel.plot,
          id: id,
          displayName: userObj.displayName,
        })
        .then((res) => {
          messageHandler(res);
        });
    }
  };

  const onClearAttachment = () => {
    setAttachment(null);
    fileInput.current.value = null;
  };

  const onChangeI = (e) => {
    setContent(e.target.files[0]);
    const {
      target: { files },
    } = e;
    const theFile = files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = (finishEvent) => {
      const {
        currentTarget: { result },
      } = finishEvent;
      setAttachment(result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(theFile);
  };

  const onSubmitF = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  const onMessageConfirm = () => {
    setMessagecondition(false);
  };

  const onCreatenovelCompleteBtn = () => {
    setCreateComplete(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="Createnovel">
      <div className="form-wrapper">
        <input
          className="title-input"
          type="text"
          ref={inputRef}
          placeholder="제목"
          onChange={getValue}
          name="title"
        />
        <CKEditor
          editor={ClassicEditor}
          data="<p>줄거리를 입력하세요.</p>"
          onChange={(event, editor) => {
            const data = editor.getData();
            setCreatenovel({
              ...createnovel,
              plot: data,
            });
          }}
        />
      </div>

      <>
        <div>
          {attachment ? (
            <div>
              <img src={attachment} width="100px" height="100px" alt="" />{" "}
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faXmark}
                className="nav_user"
                onClick={onClearAttachment}
              />
            </div>
          ) : (
            "선택된 커버 이미지가 없습니다."
          )}
        </div>
        <form onSubmit={onSubmitF}>
          <input type="file" onChange={onChangeI} ref={fileInput} />
        </form>
      </>

      <button className="submit-button" onClick={onCreatenovelBtnClick}>
        입력
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Createnovel;
```

And below is part of nodejs.

```
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: { fileSize: 1000000 },
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`running on port ${PORT}`);
});

app.post("/upload", upload.single("img"), function (req, res, next) {
  //const sql = "insert into novels (image) values (?)";
  //const filename = req.file.filename;
  //console.log(filename);
  res.send({
    fileName: req.file.filename,
  });
});
```

And this is the script in package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run dev:server\" \"npm run dev:client\"",
    "dev:server": "npm start",
    "dev:client": "cd client && npm start",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
```

The image is saved in the client's public folder, and only the name of the image is extracted and saved in mysql.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the part of your code where you try to create a directory. It looks like you might be trying to create something in `/client`, which is rooted at the top level of the filesystem, outside of your app's working area.

Comment: I don't use Express heavily, but that code snippet looks like it simply tries to _read_ the file at `__dirname + "/client/build/index.html"`. The error you're getting suggests you are trying to _write_ to `/client`. Do you use the `mkdirSync` function mentioned in the error message in your code?

Comment: I can't speak English well. So I didn't understand your "Do you use the mkdirSync function mentioned in the error message in your code?" So I'm posting my code.

Answer (score 0):

Before deploying to Heroku, you need to run

```
npm run build
```

which will convert your React App into a static application into another folder which then you could host to Heroku.

Comment: How will this help with OP's problem of not being able to write to the local filesystem? This might be a helpful comment, but it doesn't answer the question being asked. Please read [answer]. In particular, please make sure to answer the actual question.

Comment: And note that running `npm run build` before deploying is _not_ appropriate on Heroku. Heroku should be configured to run this itself as part of its build process.

Comment: I think the problem is an error when trying to upload images to heroku. So I'm trying to figure out how to aws s3. but it is very complicated